# How to reference an existing class variable using a string?

Tags: c#

I want to get a reference to an existing class variable using a string. I have seen some examples of similar things but can seem to figure this one out.

Please help with the commented section!

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int myInt;

    public MyClass( int i)
    {
        myInt = i;
    }
}

void Start ()
{
    MyClass myclass = new MyClass(1);

    MyClass myOtherClass = //Should be equal to myClass BUT I want to use the string "myClass" to reference it.
}
```

Comment: Would you like to have just one instance of MyClass running?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense, need more details.

Comment: Did you try Reflection?

Comment: No... How would I use reflection? I'm new at this bare with me please.  - It doesn't make sense? I want myOtherClass = myClass. Simple as that.

Comment: @AlbertoMonteiro: I want myOtherClass = myClass / one instance. -Leo: No... How would I use reflection? I'm new at this bare with me please.  -Cubicle: It doesn't make sense? I want myOtherClass = myClass. Simple as that. Edited question to make that more clear.

Comment: You can't access local variables through reflection.  _Why_ do you want to access it by name?  I suspect there's a better solution for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Can I just ask... is this an assignment you're doing? I've seen about 5 people ask this same question in the last 3 days now

Answer (score 1):

Local variables cannot be accessed by string name, even using reflection.  One option is to store them in a dictionary:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, MyClass>();
dict.Add("myClass", myClass);

string varName = "myClass";
MyClass myOtherClass = dict[varName];
```

But it's not clear at all *why* you want to access it by string name.   I suspect there's a better solution for your *real* problem.

Comment: almost exactly the same time, I post another answer,hahah

Comment: Thanks, Quick followup... If this where private could I do it? That is reference it via string?

Comment: Meaning a private class field?  Yes, technically you could do it, but I still think there's probably a better way to solve the underlying need.

Answer (score 1):

Though the question is kind of weird, but here is the stupid solution:

```
var instances = new Dictionary<string, MyClass>();
MyClass instance= new MyClass(1);
//the string "instance" can be replaced with "nameof(instance)" using C# 6.0
instances.Add("instance", instance);
```

To access this instance by name:

```
MyClass myOtherInstance = instances["instance"];
```

Comment: The use of nameof is in C# 6, not in .NET 4.5

Answer (score 0):

Wierd question, curious to know if this is what you wanted:

```
public class MyClass
    {
        public int myInt;

        public MyClass(int i)
        {
            myInt = i;
        }
    }

    public class Starter
    {
        private MyClass myclass;
        public void Start()
        {
            myclass = new MyClass(1);

            var type = this.GetType();

            var variable = type.GetField("myclass", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

            MyClass myOtherClass = (MyClass)variable.GetValue(this);
        }
    }
```